# Keep variable in memory between runs with python and spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I'm trying to use python to compute and experiment on some datas from some files.

The parsing and computation of those files can take up to 20 minutes and always lead to the exact same result. I want to experiment on that result.

Is there a way (programatically or with spyder) to only compute these datas once per python console and to keep them in memory so the script dont have to compute them again each time I run my code ?

Am I clear ? ^^'

Comment: Thank you @MahradHanaforoosh it's way better now !

Comment: you're welcome :). I changed my comment to an answer to help others who visit this page find the answer better. if you think it was helpful please mark it as the best answer and don't forget to upvote. thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [pickles](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-python-pickling-example/). by using them you can store the modified and parsed data on disk and then load it when you need